# Google Script Send email function Not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Using google script I need to create a function that will send email notification when a newly added cell along Column D is less than 8. However, when I tested to input a value less than or even more than 8, I haven't received an email.

```js
function sendEmailReport() {
  var ss_link = 'Google Spreadsheet URL';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('Google Spreadsheet URL').getSheetByName("Sheet Name").getRange("D:D"); //get column D in a specified sheet
  var row = ss.getLastRow(); //get the last row on the column D. The last row contains newly added row.
  var value = ss.getValue(); // then get the value of the cell at the last row along column D.
  //if the value in the newly added row is less than 8. I want to send an email
  if (value < 8) {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "Email Address",
      subject: "Sample Subject",
      body: "Sample Body" + ss_link
      name: 'Department ABC'
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `getValue()` only returns first value `D1`. Search `onEdit`   and use `e.value`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code:

```
function sendEmailReport() {
  var ss_link = 'Google Spreadsheet URL';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('Google Spreadsheet URL').getSheetByName('Sheet Name');
  var row = ss.getLastRow();
  var value = ss.getRange('D'+row).getValue();

  //if the value in the newly added row is less than 8. I want to send an email
  if (value < 8) {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: 'Email Address',
      subject: 'Sample Subject',
      body: 'Sample Body' + ss_link
      name: 'Department ABC'
    });
  }
}
```

This is a 'static' code: you have to run it manually every time you want to send the email. If you need to run it automatically it will need a more complicated solution with installable trigger `onEdit()`, etc.

Comment: I would upvote if you also explained why it didn’t work and what you changes

Comment: I'd prefer to wait for any reaction from OP first. Most likely he want `onEdit()` functionality. So it makes no sense to try to explain this code. Basically the main trouble is mentioned in the comment of @TheMaster -- `ss.getValue()` unlikely would return a value of the last cell of the range `ss`. I just show how it can be fixed. Actually, I'd prefer to use one line to get the cell 'D' from the last line: `var value = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().pop()[3]`;

Comment: Thank you so much! The revised code works.